# NSNumberFormatter desired results for UITextField

Tags: ios, uitextfield, nsnumberformatter

I'm having trouble getting the desired NSNumberFormatter results.  I've tried several combinations of properties but haven't gotten exactly what I'm looking for.

I'd like to format a UITextField as the user types with the decimal pad keyboard.

Acceptable input formats:

12

12.3

12.34

A minimum of 2 digits preceeding the decimal and a maximum of 2 digits following the decimal.
Maximum value possible in this case would be 99.99.

As the user types 1 2 3 4.. the textfield should display the following

1

12

12.3

12.34

If the user doesn't explicitly use the decimal key, it should automatically be inserted.

Here's my latest attempt, but like I said.. I've tried a lot of things

```
-(void)textFieldDidChange:(UITextField *)theTextField
{
    if (theTextField.text) {

        NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
        [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];

        NSNumber *number = [formatter numberFromString:theTextField.text];
        //[formatter setMinimumIntegerDigits:2];
        [formatter setMaximumIntegerDigits:2];

        [formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];

        theTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [formatter stringFromNumber:number]];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd choose another approach.

In textFieldDidChange do not format but validate with NSPredicate and RegEx.

```
-(void)textFieldDidChange:(UITextField *)theTextField
{
    if (theTextField.text) {
        NSString *regex = @"^[0-9]{0,2}[\\.]{0,1}[0-9]{0,2}$";
        NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", regex];
        if (![pred evaluateWithObject:mystring])
        { // Error, input not matching! Remove last added character.
            int len = theTextField.text.length-((theTextField.text.length-1 == 3) ? 2 : 1;
            theTextField.text = [theTextField.text substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, len)]; 
            // Now checks if the new length, i.e. the length when the last digit has been deleted is 3, which means that the decimal dot is the last character. If so remove 2 instead of only 1 character!
        }
        else 
        { // OKay here, do whatever
            if(theTextField.text.length == 2) // Add decimal dot if two digits have been entered!
                theTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.", theTextField.text];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This results in the input not matching every time.

Comment: Nor can you delete input

Comment: Under which circumstances does the match fail? What do you put in?

Comment: Ah. Edited the answer... Had to use {0,2} for both numbers to match zero to more integer digits and zero to more fraction digits. If you require at least one integer digit make the first {0,2} to be {1,2}

Comment: Thanks. What about not being able to delete? If I enter 12.34 then I can only delete 34.. I am always left with what precedes the decimal

Comment: I still need help with this. Your regex is close, but I can't delete the text. It also allows me to enter multiple decimal points (12.3.4)

Answer (score 0):

Try the given regular expression as-

```
 NSString *regex = @"^[0-9]{0,2}(\\.[0-9]{1,2})?";
```